# Unable to get page like list for some users using php sdk

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am facing a problem to get the page list of a user which he liked for some user.I found the issue.i.e  when we use the link https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes?access_token=AAAAAAITEghMBAPyx23APxfNtEtmhzqlGVu4pe0ZBsPStne2vo7ZC0jVbKscpLabWzhhO0zCl55Q7djG7WOk1jTXLLUQtnmd9a4Exr42SbJgZAgYH1D9 directly we are  getting the list because access token is provided by the facebook is different frm which we are getting through api.

Here is the app url which has the problem.
http://www.facebook.com/reasearchanddevelopment/app_147970198679455

Is there any solution for this problem.

Thanks,

Rajesh.

Answer (score 0):

Add "user_likes" permission to scope parameter when getting url for login user to facebook.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7601553/1285871